# fragment with large activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I downloaded this example of basic fragment from this link (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) ! It is perfect and it works on both the tablet than on the phone. but the moment that I implement on another project just goes on the phone ... and when it should open the xml file on large Tbalet the app to crash on launch ! solutions ? I lose something ? thank you!

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.chiari.nicola.myapplication/com.chiari.nicola.myapplication.MainActivity_list}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
```

this is the class

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {

String[] Headlines = {
        "Article One",
        "Article Two",
        "Article 3",
        "Article 4",
        "Article 5",
        "Article 6",
};

SearchView search_view;



OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

String[] menutitles;
TypedArray menuIcons;

CustomAdapter adapter;
private List<RowItem> rowItems;

// The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can deliver messages
public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    /** Called by HeadlinesFragment when a list item is selected */
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // We need to use a different list item layout for devices older than Honeycomb
    int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, null, false);











}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    menuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < menutitles.length; i++) {
        RowItem items = new RowItem(menutitles[i], menuIcons.getResourceId(
                i, -1));

        rowItems.add(items);
    }

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);




}




@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // When in two-pane layout, set the listview to highlight the selected list item
    // (We do this during onStart because at the point the listview is available.)
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment) != null) {
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Notify the parent activity of selected item
    mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);

    // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

}

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
int mCurrentPosition = -1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
    // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
    // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // During startup, check if there are arguments passed to the fragment.
    // onStart is a good place to do this because the layout has already been
    // applied to the fragment at this point so we can safely call the method
    // below that sets the article text.
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        // Set article based on argument passed in
        updateArticleView(args.getInt(ARG_POSITION));
    } else if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
        // Set article based on saved instance state defined during onCreateView
        updateArticleView(mCurrentPosition);
    }
}

public void updateArticleView(int position) {

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Save the current article selection in case we need to recreate the fragment
    outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
}
```

}`

```
public class MainActivity_list extends FragmentActivity
    implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

    // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
        HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
        // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }
}

public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment

    // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
    ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

    if (articleFrag != null) {
        // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

        // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
        articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);

    } else {
        // If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

        // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
        ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

large xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
          android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
          android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

normal xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".HeadlinesFragment" >



<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container">






</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment` show xml

Comment: check below answer at first .

Answer (score 0):

package name is wrong. 
check the package in which your class HeadlinesFragment is present

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment android:name="com.chiari.nicola.myapplication.HeadlinesFragment"
      android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <fragment android:name="com.chiari.nicola.myapplication.ArticleFragment"
      android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
      android:layout_weight="2"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have now found my mistake ! I had changed the name of pacchettto in large xml files .... but the app crashes comuqne ... for another error ...

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.

Answer (score 0):

You gave wrong package name reference to your xml. As per error your package name is

```
com.chiari.nicola.myapplication
```

So, in your xml you gave `com.example.android.fragments`. You need to set it to your package name. your `large.xml` should be like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment android:name="com.chiari.nicola.myapplication.HeadlinesFragment"
      android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <fragment android:name="com.chiari.nicola.myapplication.ArticleFragment"
      android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
      android:layout_weight="2"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```